# Rally custom fields changes reflect other fields

Tags: rally, code-rally

case 1 
1. Create custom fields called "completion %" which depends on child user stories. How can i fill parent user story completion % based on child user stories completion

2. Create two custom fields - start and end date => parent user stories should NOT depend on child user stories start and end date

any idea on rally custom fields changes

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should start using Portfolio items to be the parents. Having parent user stories and child user stories is from a time when Rally didn't have the capability it does now, and there are far better ways to manage your work breakdown.

What you are asking for is already available in Rally if you use Features as the parents of a collection of User Stories.